# Qt windeployqt for debug version does'nt copy all dll's

Tags: qt, qt5.10, windeployqt

i have a problem with my qt deployment under windows 10. For the beginning, i'm using QtCreator 4.5.0 and Qt 5.10 on Windows 10. For the deployment i configerd my project file like the awnser in this question ( [Automatic Copy of Dependent Files in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771039/automatic-copy-of-dependent-files-in-qt-creator) )
For more than one year it works fine but since the end of last year it does'nt. 
If i build the release version all is fine but in debug mode some dll's missing. If i copy this ones manually the program run correct otherwise no icons will be displayed. So far i can see it in git there are no modifications in the project file since it works correct at last.

---

The deployment line from project file:

```
    #######################################
    # Deploy Settings

    TARGET_CUSTOM_EXT = .exe
    DEPLOY_COMMAND = windeployqt

    ProgramData.path = C:/ProgramData/Application
    ProgramData.files += ressource/xml/config.xml
    ProgramData.files += ressource/xml/user.xml
    ProgramData.files += ressource/xml/documentation.xml
    INSTALLS += ProgramData

    # copy to make install
    CONFIG( release ) {
        AdditionalFiles.path = $${OUT_PWD}/$${DESTDIR}/ressource
        AdditionalFiles.files += ressource/xml/config.xml
        AdditionalFiles.files += ressource/xml/user.xml
        AdditionalFiles.files += ressource/xml/documentation.xml
        AdditionalFiles.files += ressource/install.nsi
        AdditionalFiles.files += release_notes/*.txt
        INSTALLS += AdditionalFiles
    }

    CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
        DEPLOY_TARGET = $$shell_quote($$shell_path($${OUT_PWD}/debug/$${TARGET}$${TARGET_CUSTOM_EXT}))
    } else {
        DEPLOY_TARGET = $$shell_quote($$shell_path($${OUT_PWD}/release/$${TARGET}$${TARGET_CUSTOM_EXT}))
    }

    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $${DEPLOY_COMMAND} $${DEPLOY_TARGET}
```

---

This is my complete Project file:

```
    QT       += core gui network widgets winextras

    TARGET = Application
    TEMPLATE = app

    TRANSLATIONS = \
        translation/Application_de.ts \
        translation/Application_en.ts \
        translation/Application_es.ts \
        translation/Application_fr.ts \
        translation/Application_nl.ts

    # Settings for favicon/tasksymbol
    win32:RC_ICONS += ressource/favicon/favicon.ico


    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
    DEFINES = QT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT

    build_pass:CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        CONFIG += warn_on
    }

    #######################################
    # Build dir settings

    Release:DESTDIR = release
    Release:OBJECTS_DIR = release/.obj
    Release:MOC_DIR = release/.moc
    Release:RCC_DIR = release/.rcc
    Release:UI_DIR = release/.ui

    Debug:DESTDIR = debug
    Debug:OBJECTS_DIR = debug/.obj
    Debug:MOC_DIR = debug/.moc
    Debug:RCC_DIR = debug/.rcc
    Debug:UI_DIR = debug/.ui

    #######################################
    # Deploy Settings

    TARGET_CUSTOM_EXT = .exe
    DEPLOY_COMMAND = windeployqt

    ProgramData.path = C:/ProgramData/Application
    ProgramData.files += ressource/xml/config.xml
    ProgramData.files += ressource/xml/user.xml
    ProgramData.files += ressource/xml/documentation.xml
    INSTALLS += ProgramData

    # copy to make install
    CONFIG( release ) {
        AdditionalFiles.path = $${OUT_PWD}/$${DESTDIR}/ressource
        AdditionalFiles.files += ressource/xml/config.xml
        AdditionalFiles.files += ressource/xml/user.xml
        AdditionalFiles.files += ressource/xml/documentation.xml
        AdditionalFiles.files += ressource/install.nsi
        AdditionalFiles.files += release_notes/*.txt
        INSTALLS += AdditionalFiles
    }

    CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
        DEPLOY_TARGET = $$shell_quote($$shell_path($${OUT_PWD}/debug/$${TARGET}$${TARGET_CUSTOM_EXT}))
    } else {
        DEPLOY_TARGET = $$shell_quote($$shell_path($${OUT_PWD}/release/$${TARGET}$${TARGET_CUSTOM_EXT}))
    }

    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $${DEPLOY_COMMAND} $${DEPLOY_TARGET}

    # The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
    # any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
    # depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
    # deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
    DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

    #######################################
    # Main Project entry
    include ( src/app.pri)

    #######################################
    # Resource files

    RESOURCES += \
        ressource/Images/Images.qrc

    #######################################
    # Distfiles
    DISTFILES += \
        ressource/install.nsi \
        favicon.ico

    # XML Files
    DISTFILES += \
        ressource/config.xml \
        ressource/user.xml \    
        ressource/documentation.xml

    # Release Notes
    DISTFILES += \
        release_notes/4_2_0.txt \
        release_notes/4_2_3.txt \
        release_notes/4_3_0.txt \
        release_notes/Template.txt

    # Translation
    DISTFILES += \
        translation/convert_cute_TS_to_gnu_PO.sh \
        translation/convert_gnu_PO_to_cute_TS.sh
```

---

Output of windeployqt --list mapping for debug and release version:
[image: Output of windeployqt --list mapping for debug and release version]

Has somebody an idea or an hint for me to find the error?

Thanks
Sven Arno Jopen

Comment: offtop - you forgot to cover your super-secret application name in the last string of powershell output on both screenshots

Comment: Thanks, it is not so secret but must not be so public that this is a part of this project :-D

Comment: File a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why there are missing dlls, but I can tell you that you can manually force them by specifying them on the command line.  In the example below, `opengl` and `printsupport` libraries are specifically called out to be copied.  You will also notice that we use `.` as our target.  This makes `windeployqt` look at all exe and dll files and see what they also need.

Example:
    `windeployqt --opengl --printsupport .`

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think you need those configurations *unless* windeployqt does not really work in `debug` mode. Note that *almost all* qt binaries include both `debug` and `release` binaries.
- To force the tool for debug binaries use  `--debug` , while `--release` generate release binaries.

`windeployqt --debug --list mapping`

Some options of the tool:

```
windeployqt:
  -?, -h, --help            Displays this help.
  -v, --version             Displays version information.
  --debug                   Assume debug binaries.
  --release                 Assume release binaries.
```

Answer (score 0):

After I made a Update from Qt 5.9.1 to 5.10.1 and Creator from 4.50 to 4.5.1.
the deployment tool works correctly... it seems that this was a version problem but because i didn't find the specific problem it's only speculative. Thanks for the answers!